# gcloud git push on Windows

Tags: windows, git

I am trouble to push code onto gcloud with
git push google master. It always says. 
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.git-helper) unrecognized arguments: --ignore-unknown

I already checked gcloud.cmd is in path and gcloud auth list shows my username on gcloud. Not sure where is --ignore-unknown coming from. 
Tom

Answer (score 0):

gcloud uses a hidden command,

```
gcloud auth git-helper
```

as a git credential helper[1] to authenticate for git push/pull operations.  The error message you're seeing is probably a sign that the `gcloud auth` component of gcloud is out of date.  Your best bet is to run

```
gcloud components update
```

to make sure all glcoud components are up to date.

[1] If you're curious about git credential helpers you might start here: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.9/gitcredentials.html.